# Update Post Meta in Front End with a form

Tags: metabox, post-meta

How I can update Existing (Back-End) metabox variable from front-End, I tried many times but I don't know why doesn't this work? Showing only old value not update, what i did wrong?

This is my Front-End Page, I'm using this code inside normal Page With shortCode and also this code between post loop.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['zon_testimonial_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['zon_testimonial_nonce'],'zon_testimonial') )
    { //if nonce check succeeds.

        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $data = array(
            'package' => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['zon_package'] )
        );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_zon_testimonial_key', $data );
    }


$data = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zon_testimonial_key', true);
$package = isset($data['package']) ? $data['package'] : '';

print_r($_POST);
?>


<form method="post" action="">
   <?php wp_nonce_field('zon_testimonial','zon_testimonial_nonce'); ?>
   <label>This is label</label>
   <input type='text' name='zon_package' value='<?php echo $package; ?>' />
   <input type='submit' value='save' />
</form>
```

Comment: The whole code (`update_post_meta()` and displaying form) is in the same place / file?

Comment: @nmr  same file.

Comment: Your shortcode works for me after adding `global $post;`,  saves and reads the data correctly. Enable [debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) in WP. Check value of post ID and `$data` before `update_post_meta`: `echo "id={$post_id}, data= " . print_r($data, true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using this code in the shortcode, I suppose the reason is the lack of post ID.

You want to get the ID of the current post from the `$post` variable, but to make it possible you need to add the `global $post;` earlier (at the beginning of the function, or at least before the `IF`).

```
global $post;
if ( isset( $_POST['zon_testimonial_nonce'] ) && 
     wp_verify_nonce($_POST['zon_testimonial_nonce'],'zon_testimonial') )
```

You can also use the [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) function to get the ID of the current queried object.

```
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();
if ( isset( $_POST['zon_testimonial_nonce'] ) && 
     wp_verify_nonce($_POST['zon_testimonial_nonce'],'zon_testimonial') )
{
    $data = array(
        'package' => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['zon_package'] )
    );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_zon_testimonial_key', $data );
}
$data = get_post_meta($post_id, '_zon_testimonial_key', true);
```

Comment: i think problem in my nonce check.

Comment: already did global scope top my code.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put this script? The form will be submitted to `index.php` if you don't specify Form Action :

```
<form method="post" action="yourfile.php">
```

Comment: You can pass an array to a [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) and the array will be serialized into a string

Comment: @nmr thank you! My mistake. I will update the answer

Comment: @Jamy same place

Comment: @NoufalBinu Is this a script in an independent file or the code inside a plugin/theme? I mean entire this code

Comment: Inside a plugin and called with a short code inside wordpress page.

Comment: @NoufalBinu can you get the data submitted when call this `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: @Jamy yeah i got value.

Comment: @NoufalBinu you should debug your code. Turn on `display_errors` setting, var_dump `$post` and the return value of `update_post_meta()` function. Make sure the conditions in the `if statement` return true, etc